# How to Reload SwiftUI View after Login

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to redirect my user after login to a separate view and it's not working.  It's staying on the login page.  I have confirmation that the authentication is working and the published variable is updating, but the view never changes.  When I print isAuthenticated in the loginViewModel, I get a result of true.

Tried implementing [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394432/navigate-after-successful-login-with-swiftui), but it's not working for my application.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp_SwiftUIApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userStatus = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if !userStatus.isAuthenticated {
            LoginView()
        } else {
            ProjectsView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    @Published var isAuthenticated: Bool = false
    @Published var authenticationDidFail: Bool = false
    
    func login() {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        Sessionservice().login(email: email, password: password) { result in
            switch result {
                case.success(let token):
                    defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isAuthenticated = true
                        self.authenticationDidFail = false
                    }
                    print(token)
                case.failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.authenticationDidFail = true
                        self.isAuthenticated = false
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

struct LoginView: View {

@StateObject private var loginVM = LoginViewModel()

@State var email: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
@ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        WelcomeText()
        WelcomeLogo()
        if loginVM.authenticationDidFail {
            Text("Invalid email or password")
                .offset(y: -10)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        LoginEmailAddressTextField(email: $loginVM.email)
        LoginPasswordField(password: $loginVM.password)
        Button(action: {
            loginVM.login()
        }){
            LoginButtonContent()
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight*0.9)
}
}
```

Comment: I see that you're not passing `LoginViewModel` to `LoginView` -- are you positive that you're using the *same instance* of `LoginViewModel` or are you inadvertently creating a new one in `LoginView`?

Comment: @jnpdx I added the LoginView for clarity above

Comment: Yep — you’re creating a new instance. Check out the answer below — it shows you how to pass the same instance to the LoginView. Check out my original answer you linked to as well, and you can see how it gets passed as a parameter.

Comment: @jnpdx See my comment to the answer below.  LoginView is not setup to accept a passed in parameter.

Comment: Right, because you've explicitly defined it as `@StateObject private var loginVM = LoginViewModel()` with `private` *and* you've given it a value of `LoginViewModel()`. Change that line to `@ObservedObject var loginVM : LoginViewModel`

Comment: Then call it with `LoginView(loginVM: userStatus)` from your `ContentView`

Comment: @jnpdx I'm getting error in LoginView: "Extra argument 'userStatus' in call"

Comment: I had deleted my answer because the other was seconds before mine, but it's getting too long to explain in the comments, so I've undeleted it. See my answer -- there are just two lines that need adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that you're using the *same instance* of the `LoginViewModel` -- if you set `isAuthenticated` to `true` on a different instance, `ContentView` won't know to update. Something like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userStatus = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if !userStatus.isAuthenticated {
            LoginView(loginVM: userStatus) //<-- HERE
        } else {
            ProjectsView()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var loginVM : LoginViewModel //<-- HERE
    
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    //etc
}
```

*Note: It might be easier to conceptualize if you change the name so that it's `userStatus` or `loginVM` in both places.*

Comment: This worked.  You're a wizard.  Thanks for the lesson.  Now to stare at this until I get it.