# How to delete all the cache or reload the application swiftui IOS CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

Hi I have an application which allows user to delete their account after they login in and went to the profile page. My application uses a viewModel to access the user details, the key concept is everytime the user login, the userViewModel will store the user object into a published variable, and that published variable is accessed every view in the application.

The problem is when user delete his account, the published user variable suddenlly becomes null and every view cannot access and caused a app crash. Is there anyway I can restart the application, enforce user back to login page without caching the other views or reload the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like app architecture could be better. Your views should either not exist after a userViewModel is null, or support a null user object by displaying relevant info (e.g. nothing, or "not logged in"). In your root class (the thing tagged with @main), in the view body add a check for if userViewModel is null, and show login view. See this for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67480055/2303348

Comment: Make the user variable optional, don’t delete the user object but mark it as deleted instead using a separate property, and probably many other routes you can take with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there would be something like this:

```
var body: some View {
    if let user = object.user {
        UserView(user: user)
    }
}
```

This way it is not possible to have a UserView without a user and thus it won't crash.

By the way, in SwiftUI there is `@FetchRequest` so you don't need to make your own view model object for fetching.